# A value 'window' cannot be determined statically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

In my Angular 12 app I have a module like

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ window.config.myConfXY ? ModuleX : ModuleY ],
  providers:    [ ... ],
  declarations: [ ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

but the compiler complains with: "A value for 'window' cannot be determined statically, as it is an external declaration."

I am trying to deploy the app in an nginx container passing in some environment variables. A generated "env.js" is referenced in index.html and defines the `window.config`.

What does the error mean and how can I fix that? Unfortunately, I found nothing useful regarding the error description on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding, this is **not possible**.

The Angular compiler needs to evaluate the NgModule `imports` during the build time itself i.e it needs to statically evaluate the conditions. It needs to know the value during the compilation and cannot wait to evaluate these until runtime. There is no way for the compiler to know about `window` object values during the compile time.

Considering we are not declaring `window` object ourselves within the application and Angular not being able to determine its value at compile time, hence the below error:

```js
A value for 'window' cannot be determined statically, as it is an external declaration.
```

One possible solution would be to make use of the environment files. We have `fileReplacements` in angular.json file and so we can define a config property within an environment file. Since we can have multiple files based on the different environments, during the build the compiler should be able to evaluate the environment config property value statically.

**Resources:**

- [Conditional Module imports](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36243)
- [How the Angular Compiler Works](https://blog.angular.io/how-the-angular-compiler-works-42111f9d2549)
- [Configure target-specific file replacements](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Using a specific `environment.ts` file for that configuration will be more effort within my CI but that's acceptable. I am curious: Would it be possible if I would switch to jit instead of aot?

Comment: Though it might work, but I wasn't exactly sure about it. So I tried the jit compilation locally by specifying something as `window['config'] ? [] : ReactiveFormsModule` within lazy loaded module and did set `window.config` value to `true` and `false` within browser console before loading the module, and it seems to be working. When setting `false` I didn't encountered any error, whereas when setting `true` I received errors like `No provider for FormBuilder!` as expected.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich My previous comment in no way is a recommendation to use JIT over AOT. With AOT one does get lots of benefits, and when using JIT one has to make lots of tradeoffs. Also [RFC: Exploration of use-cases for Angular JIT compilation mode](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/43133)  might be a good read.

Comment: Yes, AOT is definetely the better option.